# Windows Registry settings -KB updates

Tags: windows, windows-7, installshield

I want to install KB2464222 in as a prerequisite. Where does the windows adds registry key regarding this update?

Comment: I dont see any registry in this update...Also this is offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no registry entries that can tell you if a certain Windows update is installer or not. (assuming you want to use the registry to decide if the prerequisite is to installed or not)

The only way to detect the update is installed is to write your own small application that [lists the updates,](https://serverfault.com/questions/56953/how-do-i-generate-a-list-of-windows-patches-and-the-date-they-were-installed-on) and searches to the list.

This now depends on the bootstrapper IS is offering, I don't know it is capable of listening for the return code of an EXE an depending on it decides if the prerequisite should be installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

search in the registry, you can find it under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates

in 64 bit PC .